# Mapping(attaching) three items to other item

Tags: data-mapping

I have three fields to be mapped with many other elements.

So here I am attaching the screenshot which shows I am mapping cluster,hosts to product,subproduct and environment. Later I have to also show this details that these cluster and hosts are mapped to product,subproduct and environment. Currently I am showing it in table with columns but I am looking for better way to represent these data.

[image]

I am finding more intuitive and cool way to do this task so it becomes more easy and fun to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer and provide more context (and UI mocks)? Right now it's not clear who the user is, what they're mapping, and any constraints. If you provide more in-depth mocks of your efforts so far, you get better quality answers for your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your response.

Comment: @MikeM Added more details and proper screenshot to the question. I hope this will give you some context.